# Sufficient conditions for positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

- Is a symmetric matrix with positive terms (i.e., $a_{ij} > 0$) and positive determinant positive semidefinite?
- Is a symmetric matrix with positive terms, positive determinant, and
  terms that satisfy $a_{ij}^2 \leq a_{ii} a_{jj}$ positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your first question is negative. Consider$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&2\\2&2&2\\2&2&1\end{pmatrix}.$$Each entry is greater than $0$ and the determinant is $2$. However$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&1\end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=-2.$$

Answer (score 4):

b) The following statements are equivalent:

- The symmetric matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite
- All eigenvalues are non negative
- All the principal minors of $A$ are non negative.
- There exists a $B$ such that $A = B^{T}B$ where $B$ can be thought of as a square root of a positive operator.

[1] Kreyszig, Erwin. Introductory functional analysis with applications. Vol. 1. New York: wiley, 1989.

Comment: Can you provide the specific page? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

a) The answer is no. Look at the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&1&1\\
2&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&2\\
1&1&2&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
All its entries are positive. Its determinant is 5, and thus positive. But one of its eigenvalues is $-1$, and thus it is not positive semidefinite.

b) I could not find a counter-example at this stage.